# Turning selection of divs into a grid with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page with a load of divs that I'm trying to put into 4 columns dynamically with jquery.

http://www.jeremymcminn.com/trent

Instead of the divs .item being put inside the 4 columns separately, they are nested down from one another all in one column (apart from one on column 2).

Any help would be appreciated to what I am doing wrong and how I can get the .item divs into 4 columns.  The code below is what I am using.

```
$( function() {

    var kLazyLoad = $K.lazyLoad,
        kLazyLoadInit = $K.lazyLoadInit,
        kPageLoading = false,
        kColNext = 0,
        kColLength = parseInt( $('#grid').attr('class').replace('col-',''), 10 ),
        regaleLazyLoad = function(override) {
            if (override) { kLazyLoad(); }
        },
        regaleLazyLoadInit = function(override) {
            $K.lazyLoadInit();
            setTimeout( function() { $K.lazyLoad(true); }, 100);
        }

    $K.lazyLoad = regaleLazyLoad;
    $K.lazyLoadInit = kLazyLoadInit;

    (function() {
        var colContainer = '';
        for ( var i = 0, len = kColLength; i < len; i++ ) {
            colContainer += $('#grid').html();
        }
        $('#grid').html(colContainer);
    })();

    var updateGrid = function() {
        kPageLoading = false;
        $('#container > .item').each(function(i,item) {
            $(item).appendTo($('.column:eq('+kColNext+')'));
            kColNext = (kColNext+1 >= kColLength) ? 0 : kColNext+1;
        });
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            var longestCol, shortestCol;
            $('.column').each(function(i,column) {
                if (!longestCol || $(column).outerHeight(true) > longestCol.outerHeight(true)) {
                    longestCol = $(column);
                }
                if (!shortestCol || $(column).outerHeight(true) < shortestCol.outerHeight(true)) {
                    shortestCol = $(column);
                }
            });
            var lastItem = longestCol.find('.item:last');
            lastItem.css('display','none');
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                if (longestCol.outerHeight(true) - shortestCol.outerHeight(true) > shortestCol.outerHeight(true)/3) {
                    lastItem.appendTo(shortestCol);
                }
                lastItem.css('display','block');
                regaleLazyLoad(true);
            },1);
        },50);
    }

    $(window).off('.rjs').on('scroll.rjs', function() {
        regaleLazyLoad(true);
        if (kPageLoading) { return false; }
        if ( $(document).scrollTop() + $('#grid').offset().top > ($('#grid').offset().top + $('#grid').height()) - $(window).height()*3 || $('.k-lazy-loading').length < 15 ) {
            kPageLoading = true;
            $K.infinity.next();
        }
    });

    $K.infinity.check = $.noop;

    $(window).on('k-infinite-loaded', updateGrid).trigger('k-infinite-loaded');
    $(window).on('k-resize', function() {
        regaleLazyLoadInit();
    });

    regaleLazyLoadInit();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do this is to use UL/LI instead of DIVs. Then float the LI elements left and make the UL wrapper 4 x the width of the LI elements. You should be able to do this with CSS.

A group of elements is really a list anyway, to the UL/LI pattern makes more semantic sense.

Use, for example:

```
ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    width: 800px
}

li {
    float:left;
    width:200px;

}
```